# Run Different Macros Depending Active.Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to run different Macros depending on which sheet is active. However, if I run the code below when the first sheet is active the code works but is also incorrectly running on the second sheet. If I run the code when the second sheet is active, the right code is applied but then nothing happens on the first sheet. Does anyone know how I can adjust the code to correct this?

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

If ActiveSheet.Name = "SOGR Initiative Tracker" Then
    SetOnkey (True)
ElseIf ActiveSheet.Name = "Contract Management" Then
    SetOnkey2 (True)

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is `SetOnkey` ?

Comment: `Worksheet_Activate` is in the code module for a specific sheet, so why does it need to test which sheet it's in?  It will always be the same sheet.  If you need a test like this then you should probably be using `Workbook_SheetActivate` in the `ThisWorkbook` code module.  That has a parameter `Sh` which is the sheet being activated.

Comment: assuming `SetOnKey` is running the `Application.SetKey` method somewhere, you might need to consider un-setting that when you change sheets

Comment: Thanks for your responses! SetonKey / SetOnKey2 is the name of the macro I'm trying to run depending on which sheet is active.

Comment: Thanks for your responses! @SJR SetonKey / SetOnKey2 is the name of the macro I'm trying to run depending on which sheet is active.

Comment: @TimWilliams The SetOnKey Macros are for tabing through a range of cells and the sequence of which tabs to move through vary between both sheets. How is it best to use the Workbook_SheetActivate instead? Sorry, I'm very new to VBA. Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Tim Williams's comment, use the `Workbook` level `SheetActivate` event and that way you can run different macros depending on which sheet is activated.

This code must go in the `ThisWorkbook` module.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

If Sh.Name = "SOGR Initiative Tracker" Then
    SetOnkey (True)
ElseIf Sh.Name = "Contract Management" Then
    SetOnkey2 (True)
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: That did it!! Thanks so much!